# Algorithm design - Bipartite graph problem modeling

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, operations-research, bipartite-graphs

Given two machines $A$ and $B$, with a collections of jobs in time intervals $(s,f)$ with '$s$' and '$f$' being start and finish times respectively.

Is there a way to schedule all jobs?

The problem must be formulated as an algorithmic problem and an algorithm solution must be presented.

I'm lost on how to conceptualize this problem, I've thought about setting up a bipartite graph with a set of nodes $X$ and $Y$, $X$ being the jobs, $Y$ being the machines or would setting $Y$ to be available time slots of the two machines be the better choice?

Comment: Both machines are capable of doing all jobs? At the same speed/same resource requirements, or varying per task?

Comment: Yes, they both work at the same speed, I believe it is about filling as many jobs as possible with two machines

Comment: Are you saying each job has a predetermined start and end time that must be used (e.g., job 1 must start at time 7 and end at time 12, regardless of whether that's feasible or not)?